# Remote access sql server 2008 in c# application

Tags: c#, sql-server

i developed crm application in c# with sql server 2008 as a database now i want my app should have install in different computer but there should be only one database through which all users should use one data base through WIFI or LAN. How can i do it please help that will be appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

If they have network access, then this is just a case of changing the SQL connection string to indicate the location of the actual server. In particular, the `Server` or `Data Source` parameter of the connection string. The server must also allow non-local connections (configuration options), have sufficient and appropriate licenses, have user access configuration that permits the new callers, and must have the correct firewall holes open.